# I can't figure out why the URL to the feed doesn't work when it is in a list item

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

[I am editing this question to hopefully get a useful answer. The one answer provided does not answer the question about why the link for the RSS feed doesn't work when it is put in a list item. It also is a useless answer because if you remove /feed from the link, you won't go to the RSS feed page--it just reloads the current page.]

I have a bulleted list of other sites (such as social media accounts) that are related to the website. A link to the RSS feed for the website is included in the list. Each list item uses a representative icon instead of text. In the first four list items the icon is an SVG image used as a background image. You can click on the background SVG image and go to the URL in the list item. In the fifth list item, I have to use a graphic icon because the SVG icon for RSS (#icon-rss) doesn't work. I would think that the action would be the same whether the icon is an SVG image or a graphic image.

My problem is that they don't act the same. The link for the RSS feed works when used on its own in a browser so I know the link is a working link. But that RSS feed link does not work when it is in the list item that uses a background image for a bullet. When I click on the background image for RSS, a loading animation appears in the middle of the page and just spins and spins--it never loads the feed page. It behaves the same way in Firefox and Safari.

CSS for the SVG images change the color of the icon on hover. There is also CSS that switches one color of the background image of the RSS icon to a different colored image on hover.

Why doesn't the feed link work when it is in a list item with an image? 
It works in a list item that has no image:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/feed">RSS feed</a>.</li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks.

Here is the CSS:

```
.sidebar-social-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: -0.3em 0 -0.1em 0;
}

.sidebar-social-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-social-navigation li a:link {
    background-color: #2222ac;  /*----Persian blue ----*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #fefdff;  /*----Splashed white ----*/
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}

.sidebar-social-navigation li a:visited {
    color: #fefdff;  /*----Splashed white ----*/
}

.sidebar-social-navigation li a:hover,
.sidebar-social-navigation li a:focus,
.sidebar-social-navigation li a:active {
    background-color: #129e6c;    /*   pool table green    */
}

.sidebar-social-navigation .icon {
    height: 28px;
    top: 12px;
    width: 28px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.sidebar-social-navigation .rssbluicon {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/rss-logo-blue-28x28.png');
}

.sidebar-social-navigation .rssbluicon:hover,
.sidebar-social-navigation .rssbluicon:focus,
.sidebar-social-navigation .rssbluicon:active {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/rss-logo-green-28x28.png');
}
```

Here is the HTML of three of the list items:

```
<div class="sidebar-social-navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/BaeeArtists" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span class="screen-reader-text">Twitter</span><svg class="icon icon-twitter" aria-hidden="true" role="img"> <use href="#icon-twitter" xlink:href="#icon-twitter"></use> </svg></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/baeeorg" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span class="screen-reader-text">Facebook</span><svg class="icon icon-facebook" aria-hidden="true" role="img"> <use href="#icon-facebook" xlink:href="#icon-facebook"></use> </svg></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/feed" title="RSS feed"><span class="screen-reader-text">RSS</span><img class="icon rssbluicon" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: For a working / nonworking  example, see the sidebar in https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/about-us/#more-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with a plugin script you are using "nextgen fancybox".

It appears that, by default, it looks for every `<img>` on the page whose parent is an `<a>` tag, and attaches fancybox handling to it.

Check the configuration of that plugin, and see if you can change how it selects images to attach to.  Otherwise, you could avoid using an `<img>` tag in that link (since it is just a placeholder anyway).

Comment: You are right. I checked the NextGen Gallery and the Lightbox Fancybox effects were set to apply to all images. I reset the it to only apply to Nextgen images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- [RSS feed](https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org).

just remove the /feed and it will work.

Comment: No it won't work because then the link won't go to the feed. It will just reload the home page.